# calculate Pi in java (fast)

Tags: java, pi

I want to make a fast generator (if possible, in Java) which gives me Pi (with decimals of course).
I have made one already, which uses a for loop and BigDecimals:

```
BigDecimal pi;
    pi = new BigDecimal("0");
    BigDecimal divide = new BigDecimal("1");
    long max = <Any Number>;

        for (long l = 1; l < max; l++) {

        BigDecimal two = new BigDecimal("2"); //it gave me an error if it wasn't a BigDecimal.
        BigDecimal four = new BigDecimal("4");
        BigDecimal divide2 = divide.add(two);
        BigDecimal divideend = four.divide(divide, 50, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
        BigDecimal divideend2 = four.divide(divide2, 50, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
        pi = pi.add(divideend);
        pi = pi.subtract(divideend2);
        System.out.println(pi.toString() + "                   " + i + " of " + max);
        divide = divide.add(vier);
        }
    System.out.println(pi.toString() + "      finished.");
```

the problem with this is:
I wanted to let it run for 500.000.000 times (500 Million), it took just over 5 hours and had "only" about 12 correct decimal places... is there any faster solution?

EDIT: You don't have to help me anymore, I already have a solution (If anyone else needs that too: here it is)

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Pitest3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    BigDecimal pi = new BigDecimal("3");
    long l = 1l;
    long max = 100000; //How often, the more, the more exact
    BigDecimal axbxc;
    BigDecimal divide1;
    BigDecimal divide2;
    BigDecimal divide3;
    divide1 = new BigDecimal("2");
    divide2 = new BigDecimal("3");
    divide3 = new BigDecimal("4");
    BigDecimal four = new BigDecimal("4");
    BigDecimal sumthing1;
    BigDecimal sumthing2;
    BigDecimal two = new BigDecimal("2");
    BigDecimal sumthing3;
    BigDecimal sumthing4;


    while (l < max) {

        sumthing1 = divide1.multiply(divide2);
        axbxc = sumthing1.multiply(divide3);

        sumthing2 = four.divide(axbxc, 100, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);

        pi = pi.add(sumthing2);

        divide1 = divide1.add(two);
        divide2 = divide2.add(two);
        divide3 = divide3.add(two);

        sumthing3 = divide1.multiply(divide2);
        axbxc = sumthing3.multiply(divide3);

        sumthing4 = four.divide(axbxc, 100, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);

        pi = pi.subtract(sumthing4);

        divide1 = divide1.add(two);
        divide2 = divide2.add(two);
        divide3 = divide3.add(two);

        System.out.println(pi.toString() + "            " + l + " of " + max)

        l++;



    }

    System.out.println(pi.toString() + "   finished!");

}
```

}

Comment: Well first of all you constantly construct `two` and `four`. But furthermore there are faster methods: http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/PiProgram/pifast.html

Comment: that's right, but I wanted to make it myself :)  Edit: still thanks :D

Comment: Have a look at the Wikipedia article on Pi for some ideas.  Of course `Math.PI` is virtually instantaneous but only good out to 15 or 16 digits...

Comment: @Kevin Anderson: Ok, I just missed a few Lines and now I have a much better one :) thanks, will add it to the main-post

Comment: Rather post your answer as an answer, not an edit.

Comment: If this answers you question, you should put it as an answer, and then (eventually) accept it.